# If else statement for finding the index of a character in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, indexing, character

For some reason without the else statement the code finds the indexes of the characters in the string. However, when I add the else statement to declare if a character is not found. All it does is give me the else statement even if the character is in the string.

```
#Function takes a character and a string and returns the index of the character
#found in the string.
def whereIsItS(letter, word):
    #Start finding the index of characters in the string starting at 0.
    letInWord = 0
    #For loop to find specific characters in a string.
    for l in word:
        #If the letter is found it returns the index of the letter.
        if l == letter:
        #Moves to the next character in the string.
            letInWord += 1
        else:
            return "It is not there."
    #Returns the index of the character found the string.        
    return word.index(letter)
```

I just can't seem to figure out why it works without the else statement, but not with the else statement.

Comment: because if first letter of the word is not the required letter; it returns imediately. You could do much better to compute the index. I suppose that you want to avoid the exception returned by `index`.

Comment: Your function has 11 lines of code (I counted!) which are pointless and then it returns the result from builtin `index` method. Why?

Comment: I'm still in my programming infancy and figured I had to have the for loop count through the characters in the string in order to get the indexes. I only started 2 weeks ago >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` will always exit from a function and not continue any loops you are performing.

You either `print` it's not there but that wouldn't even be true because you're printing for the current letter.

This is relatively simple to achieve with the following:

```
def whereIsItS(letter, word):
    if letter in word:
        return word.index(letter)
    else:
        return "Letter {0} not in word {1}".format(letter, word)
```

If the letter is in the word, return its index, if not, return the message specifying it wasn't found.

Further trimmed with a conditional expression to:

```
def whereIsItS(letter, word):
    return word.index(letter) if letter in word else "Letter {0} not in word {1}".format(letter, word)
```

Comment: You if else statement worked for me. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the problematic code:

```
for l in word:
    #If the letter is found it returns the index of the letter.
    if l == letter:
    #Moves to the next character in the string.
        letInWord += 1
    else:
        # You end the loop here
        # return "It is not there."
        # try this:
        print("It is not there.")
```

As you can see, `return` exits the function in the middle of the loop. You should use `print()` if you don't want to leave the for loop.

Keep in mind that you can just use the `word.index(letter)` and don't need that whole for loop like so:

```
def whereIsItS(letter, word):
    try:
        return word.index(letter)
    except ValueError:
        print("letter not in string")
```

Comment: This along with Jim's explanation helped me. Thank you so much. :)

I had issues with print repeating in the operator several times (probably because of the for loop).

Answer (score 0):

You are returning function in `else` condition.
Change `return "It is not there."` to `print("It is not there.")`

Comment: I had an issue with print because it would repeat the printed string multiple times until it reached the end of the targeted string.

Answer (score 0):

Your error has been explained by me & other people in other answers.

Now let's avoid doing unefficient code. Here are 3 efficient ways of doing it
(still the

1. use `enumerate` to get the index and the value. First occurrence: you can return the index

code:

```
def whereIsItS(letter, word):
    #Start finding the index of characters in the string starting at 0.
    #For loop to find specific characters in a string.
    for i,l in enumerate(word):
        #If the letter is found it returns the index of the letter.
        if l == letter:
            return i
    return "It is not there."
```

2. try `index` and catch the exception (it seems that your pre-check was to avoid this exception)

code:

```
def whereIsItS(letter, word):
    try:
        return word.index(letter)
    except ValueError:
        return "It is not there."
```

3. use `str.find`. It looks for substrings, so it can look for a sole letter too (and unlike `index` does not throw exceptions but just returns `-1`)

code:

```
def whereIsItS(letter, word):
    idx = word.find(letter)
    if idx>=0:
        return idx
    else:
        return "It is not there."
```

of course, the return value when letter isn't here is really not practical. I would have chosen `-1` (like `find` does) or `None`

Comment: You guys are the best. Thank you for the help and quick replies. :)